# How to use NPOI operation to add a blank page in Word and make this specific blank page landscape oriented？

Tags: c#, .net-core

When I use this method, it causes all pages to become landscape oriented

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
var para = doc.CreateParagraph();
var run = para.CreateRun();
run.SetText("Hello World!");
run.AddBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
CT_SectPr SectPr = new CT_SectPr();
SectPr.pgSz.w = (ulong)16838;
SectPr.pgSz.h = (ulong)11906;
doc.Document.body.sectPr = SectPr;
```

I would like to add only this page horizontally